# Angular not showing value in input when using ngModel

Tags: angular

I'm using Angular 14, when I put this code, it works fine and the value is initialized.

```
<input type="text" name="name" value="John" >
```

But when I add ngModel, the value is no longer initialized, and nothing is showed in the text box.

```
<input type="text" ngModel name="name" value="John" >
```

How can I put a value in text box with ngModel ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MyComponent.component.html

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="name" />
```

MyComponent.component.ts

```
...
class MyComponent {
  public name = "Jhon";
}
```

And as you update the input, the variable name will be updated. If you dont want it updated just use **[ngModel]** instead of **[(ngModel)]**

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you imported the `FormsModule from @angular/forms`
2. Use the banana box syntax, `[(ngModel)]="value"` or `[ngModel]="value"` or `ngModel="value"` or `(ngModel)="value"` base on what you want to achieve.

You can check the binding section of the Angular documentation to understand the differences:

https://angular.io/guide/binding-overview

Answer (score 0):

Try doing something like this instead

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="varName">
<p>{{ varName }}</p>
```